# UWP launch uri method LaunchUriAsync failed

Tags: uwp, launch

I try to launch a https link with code

```
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(url));
```

But the result returns `false`, I use chrome/Edge to open the same PDF file and click on the link, it can work well, and directly open the link in Chrome/Edge also work well. So I want to know why the `LaunchUriAsync` failed, can anyone help? I find that there is method called `LaunchUriForResultsAsync`, but when I set the Luanch option as `new LauncherOptions()` it will tell me the parameter is incorrect.

PS:  I call it from UI thread, and also I can successfully open https link like https://www.google.com.hk/webhp?hl=zh-CN&sourceid=cnhp&gws_rd=ssl.

Comment: Is the URL really correctly formed? And is it an internet file or a intranet (or localhost) file?

Comment: It is an internet file.

Comment: Is it confidential or could you post the URL? I would suggest using Fiddler2 to check if the request actually starts when the code is executed.

Comment: Yes, it is confidential, I will check it by the tool provide by you. Actually I remember in former few months I can open it successfully, I wonder are there any update of the method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anyone meet the same question, my solution is setting Capability privateNetworkClientServer of app package manifest.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer no longer valid, OP clarified the `Launcher` is used from UI thread.**

You have to make sure you are calling the `Launcher` methods from the UI thread. If you call the methods from a non-UI thread, they will invariably fail. The return value is then `false` and nothing is launched, which seems like your case.

As a result, you also cannot launch a URI from a background task.

To make sure the URL is interpreted correctly, you can also add a second parameter to the `Uri` constructor - `UriKind.Absolute`

Comment: I call it from UI method, because it can successfully open other links like http

Comment: Oh I see, that is very unusual then :-O.